# What sql call should I use to get 10 newest entries in a table by a datetime type?

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a table that has three columns: id, song, time_played. id and song are ints and time_played is a datetime data type. how to i get the 10 newest records with the datetime column? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY time_played DESC
LIMIT 10
```